# F# deserializing array of arrays

Tags: arrays, f#, deserialization

I have to read in some data from a file that is stored as JSON Arrays. Basically the data represents a binary tree with labels for the nodes and values on the leafs and stylized a line looks like:

[label1,[label2,[label3,w],x],[label4,y,z]]

with arbitrary levels of depth on all branches. Now ultimately I'm looking to transform this into a tree-structure, but a first step is reading it in.

The following C# code works (using the System.Web.Extensions.dll):

```cs
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename))
{
    var data = jss.Deserialize<object[]>(line);
}
```

With "works" I mean that on the example given above, data.[1] is again an array of objects. A direct port to F# is

```
let data = 
   let jss = new JavaScriptSerializer()
   System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
       |> Seq.map (fun line -> jss.Deserialize<obj[]>(line))
```

However, applying this to the example does result in data.[1] being an object rather than an array of objects.

I considered replacing the deserialization by

```
       |> Seq.map (fun line -> jss.Deserialize<seq<obj[]>(line))
```

but that doesn't work as (in my example) label1 is a string and (obviously) can't be converted to System.Object[]. I've also tried wrapping the C# code in a static class and then using this class to read in the data in F#, but that doesn't work either. I know that I could use an external JSON parser, but since using the JavaScriptSerializer does work in C#, my stubborness is kicking in and I'd like to do this in F# this way too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you could use the [JSON Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.com/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html) to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
#r "System.Web.Extensions"

open System.Web.Script.Serialization

let jss = new JavaScriptSerializer()
let data = jss.Deserialize<obj[]>("""["label1",["label2",["label3","w"],"x"],["label4","y","z"]]""")
let doesItWork = data.[1].GetType() = typeof<obj[]>
```

Could you provide a more complete example of what's not working for you?

Comment: The PC I have access to right now, doesn't support F# 3.0, so the triple quoted string doesn't work for me. However, for me `data.[1].GetType() = typeof<obj[]>` returns true as well but at the same time something like `(data.[1]).[0]` doesn't work, altough `(data.[1] :?> obj[]).[0]` does.


Marking this as answered as I'll cast my way through the remainder of the data retrieval, but not sure I understand the difference in behaviour vs C# though.

Comment: @Bram - I'm surprised that your C# code doesn't need a corresponding cast, too (unless you're using `dynamic` somewhere).

Comment: I was not using ``dynamic`` in my C# code anywhere. Anyway, what I wanted to work is now working and for the time being I'm not going to pursue what is causing the difference: too little time and far too little knowledge of MSIL to compare the two. Thanks for your help.